# AWS Athena query to get only one object in array

Tags: mysql, amazon-athena, mysql-json

My data looks like this (table name: test_table):

```
{
    timestamp: 'some_timestamp',
    headers: [{'name': 'test', 'value': 'sth'}, {'name': 'test2', 'value': 'sth2'}, {'name': 'test3', 'value': 'sth3'}]
}
```

How can I select only `{'name': 'test2', 'value': 'sth2'}` dynamically, ie. where condition is: `name` needs to have value of`test2` and we don't know which object it is within the array.

I've tried:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(headers, 'one', 'test2', NULL, '$[*].name') IS NOT NULL
FROM test_table
```

Comment: Why would you store this data in JSON when it makes it so difficult to query the data? Just store it in normal form, in a second table with columns `name` and `value`. Each name/value pair is stored on its own row. Then you can query `SELECT ... FROM test_table_headers WHERE name = 'test2'`.

Comment: This is a structure I cannot modify as this comes as it is from aws waf firewall logs